# How can I make a original picture and its mirrored image merge together to be one imager in C#?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

The original picture:
[The original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJRI8.jpg)

How I want to display it:
[Original picture with mirrored image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Airu.jpg)

So far, I believe I will need to make a copy of original picture(transformPic) into another variable (lets call it Temp), then resize transformedPic for double width.  Copy Temp into transformedPic.  Then I will store a mirrored image of the original picture into Temp and copy it into the second half of transformedPic.

My code so far:

```
int Height = transformedPic.GetLength(0); //rows
                    int Width = transformedPic.GetLength(1); //columns


                    Color Temp;
                    //copying transformedPic into temp variable
                    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
                        {
                            Temp = transformedPic[i, j];
                            transformedPic[i, j] = transformedPic[i, j];
                            transformedPic[i, j] = Temp;
                        }
                    }

                    //doubling the width of transformedPic
                    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Width*2; j++)
                        {
                            transformedPic[i, j-1] = transformedPic[i, j-1];
                        }
                    }

                    //copying temp into transformedPic variable
                    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
                        {
                            Temp = transformedPic[i, j];
                            transformedPic[i, j] = transformedPic[i, j];
                            transformedPic[i, j] = Temp;
                        }
                    }

                    //Mirroring original picture horizontally in Temp variable
                    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Width / 2; j++)
                        {
                            Temp = transformedPic[i, j];
                            transformedPic[i, j] = transformedPic[i, Width - 1 - j];
                            transformedPic[i, Width - 1 - j] = Temp;
                        }
                    }
```

How can I store the Temp array(mirrored original image) into the second half of the transformedPic(original picture) and both of them one picture itself?

Comment: I think it would easier and a lot faster if you do it like this: Use a (valid) Graphics object and its DrawImage call. To create the mirror image you can mirror the graphics coordinates with ScaleTransform(-1, 1).

Comment: Or `transformPic.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);`