# How can I make a original picture and its mirrored image merge together to be one image in C#?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

The original picture:
[The original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJRI8.jpg)

[image]

How I want to display it:
[Original picture with mirrored image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Airu.jpg)

[image]

So far, I believe I will need to make a copy of original picture(transformPic) into another variable (lets call it Temp), then resize transformedPic for double width.  Copy Temp into transformedPic.  Then I will store a mirrored image of the original picture into Temp and copy it into the second half of transformedPic.

My code so far:

```
int Height = transformedPic.GetLength(0); //rows
                    int Width = transformedPic.GetLength(1); //columns


                    Color Temp;
                    //copying transformedPic into temp variable
                    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
                        {
                            Temp = transformedPic[i, j];
                            transformedPic[i, j] = transformedPic[i, j];
                            transformedPic[i, j] = Temp;
                        }
                    }

                    //doubling the width of transformedPic
                    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Width*2; j++)
                        {
                            transformedPic[i, j-1] = transformedPic[i, j-1];
                        }
                    }

                    //copying temp into transformedPic variable
                    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
                        {
                            Temp = transformedPic[i, j];
                            transformedPic[i, j] = transformedPic[i, j];
                            transformedPic[i, j] = Temp;
                        }
                    }

                    //Mirroring original picture horizontally in Temp variable
                    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Width / 2; j++)
                        {
                            Temp = transformedPic[i, j];
                            transformedPic[i, j] = transformedPic[i, Width - 1 - j];
                            transformedPic[i, Width - 1 - j] = Temp;
                        }
                    }
```

How can I store the Temp array(mirrored original image) into the second half of the transformedPic(original picture) and both of them one picture itself?

I have to do all this with the concepts of copying, resizing, and for looping 2D arrays.

Comment: This article will be helpful.[How to create a mirror image in CSharp using Visual Studio](https://dyclassroom.com/csharp-project/how-to-create-a-mirror-image-in-csharp-using-visual-studio)

Comment: You are not supüposed to repost a question!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what you are asking, you could use the following.

```
public static unsafe Bitmap SomeMethod(Bitmap original)
{
   int w = original.Width, w2 = w * 2, h = original.Height;   
   var combined = new Bitmap(w*2,h);

   var originalData = original.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
   var combineData = combined.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w2, h), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

   try
   {
      var spanOrig = new ReadOnlySpan<int>(originalData.Scan0.ToPointer(),w*h );
      var spanCombined = new Span<int>(combineData.Scan0.ToPointer(), w2 * h);

      for (var y = 0; y < h; y++)
      {
         // might as well do a direct memory copy since we know part of the new image is the same
         Buffer.MemoryCopy(
             (int*)originalData.Scan0 + y * w, 
             (int*)combineData.Scan0 + y * w2, 
             w * sizeof(int), w * sizeof(int));

         for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) 
            spanCombined[w + x + y * w2] = spanOrig[w - x - 1 + y * w];
      }
   }
   finally
   {
      // unlock the bitmap
      original.UnlockBits(originalData);
      combined.UnlockBits(combineData);
   }

   return combined;
}
```

**Usage**

```
using var original = new Bitmap(@"D:\uJRI8.jpg");
using var result = SomeMethod(original);

// safe it how you like
result.Save(@"D:\Result.bmp");
```

Some notes :

1. `MemoryCopy` is not CLS-compliant, though all you really need to do is copy the original scan line to the new scanline. It's just an extra loop and wouldn't be the much slower (if any).
2. `Span<int>` here is not needed at all, but I find them neater then pointer access syntax
3. This lacks a large amount of sanity checks and input validation
4. You will need to mark the project to allow unsafe code. This is supper fast and efficient, and to keep that fast you will need it

**Output**

[image: result]

Comment: There are at least two ways to avoid unsafe code, as commented in the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65848217/how-can-i-make-a-original-picture-and-its-mirrored-image-merge-together-to-be-on). Both also are a lot shorter..

Comment: @Taw, not really sure why you down voted, \*shrug\* but that aside id be interested to see the benchmarks, just for morbid curiosity. I know the jittering for the loops and the optimisation of the copy would be hard to beat, but who knows

Comment: The question is a repost, so your answer belongs to the original post. (I you move it there one could upvote it and vote to close this post as a duplicate..) I won't do a benchmark, but I do expect either sytem call will be hard to beat.

Comment: @Taw, I am out stm, but I'll move as soon as I can ,thanks for letting me know